# Extracting posterior probabilities for all the pdf-ids per frame in kaldi

Tags: speech-recognition, kaldi

Is it possible in kaldi to extract the posterior probability, for each 
pdf-ids in the decision tree? I am currently training a CNN model, that can replicate the results of the GMM. My CNN is currently only trained to predict the true phone, meaning I will be in trouble if multiple pdf-ids are used for the decoding a phone..

I am currently extracting the posterior probability as such

```
ali-to-pdf final.mdl ark:ali.1 ark:- | ali-to-post ark:- ark,t:-
```

Which print out something like this:

```
0_1_1_1_1_1_1_1 [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 2 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 1 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 0 1 ]
```

based on a decision tree:

[image]

Which only gives me the best posterior probability, and not all of them per frame.. Is it possible to get the posterior of all the pdf-ids per frame, rather than the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably do something like

ali-to-pdf ark:1.ali ali, t:- | ali-to-post ark:- ark,t:output